# redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage

Tags: react-native, react-redux

In using AsyncStorage but is not working.I did reset cache,build app.And ERROR  redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.
App@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.loginfo&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:109909:44
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.loginfo&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:76902:36
LoginFo(RootComponent)@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.loginfo&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:83297:28
package.json

```js
{
  "name": "LoginFo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Store.js

```js
    
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import productsReducer from '../store/products-reducer';
import loginReducer from '../store/login-reducer';
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage
  };
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    productsReducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, productsReducer),
    loginReducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, loginReducer)
  });
  console.log("NoOOWshoon root reducer",)
  export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

product-actions.js

```js
  

      import localStorage from "redux-persist/es/storage";
        import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
        
        export const ADD_PRODUCT = "ADD_PRODUCT";
        export const LOAD_PRODUCTS = "LOAD_PRODUCTS";
        
        export const addProduct = product => {
          return async dispatch => {
            const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(product)
            localStorage.setItem('products', jsonValue)
        
            console.log("------",product)
          
            dispatch({
              type: ADD_PRODUCT,
              data: {
                product
              }
            });
          };
        };
        
        export const loadProducts = () => {
          return async dispatch => {
            const products = localStorage.getItem('products');
            /* const products = value ? JSON.parse(value) : []; */
            const product = JSON.parse(products)
            console.log("skdlfksldkf",product);
        
            dispatch({
              type: LOAD_PRODUCTS,
              data: product
            });
          };
        };
```

login-actions.js

```js
    import localStorage from "redux-persist/es/storage";
    import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
    export const ADD_USER = "ADD_USER";
    export const LOAD_USER = "LOAD_USER";
    
    export const addUser = (user) => {  
      return async dispatch => {
        
        /* const value = await localStorage.getItem('users');
        const users = value ? JSON.parse(value) : [];
         console.log("ADDUSER+++++",user) */
        /* users.push(user); */
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(user)
        localStorage.setItem('users', jsonValue)
        /* await AsyncStorage.removeItem('users') */
        console.log("------",user)
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_USER,
          data: {
            user
          }
        });
      };
    };
    
    export const loadUser = () => {
      return async dispatch => {
        const users = localStorage.getItem('users');
        /* const products = value ? JSON.parse(value) : []; */
        const user = JSON.parse(users)
        console.log("skdlfksldkf",user);
    
        dispatch({
          type: LOAD_USER,
          data: user
        });
      };
    };
```

signUpscreen.js

```js
    import React, {useState,useEffect,useContext,useRef} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
    import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
    import CustomInput from '../../components/CustomInput';
    import UserContext from '../../contexts/UserContext';
    import Modal4 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal4';
    import Modal5 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal5';
    import Modal6 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal6';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { addUser } from '../../store/login-actions';
    function SignUpScreen(props) {  
      const {navigation} = props;
      const [visible4, setVisible4] = useState(false);
      const [visible5, setVisible5] = useState(false);
      const [visible6, setVisible6] = useState(false);
      const users = useSelector(state => state.loginReducer.user);
      console.log("usereuureuruerueur",users)
      
      const state = useContext(UserContext);
      const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: "Bataa",
        email: "byamba@gmail.com",
        password: "20000",
        passwordRepeat:
          "20000"
      });
      
      
     
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const onRegisterPressed = async() => {
        
      if (user.username.length === 0) {
         setVisible4(true);
          return;
        }
      if (user.password !== user.passwordRepeat) {
          setVisible5(true);
          return;
        }
        dispatch(addUser(user))
        console.log("HuuuchinUSERS=================",users)
      /*   const userSearch = users.filter(el => el.username === user.username)
        console.log("HaiserUSER+++++++++",userSearch)
      if(userSearch){
        setVisible6(true);
        return;
      }
      else{
        dispatch(addUser(user))
        
         state.setIsLoggedIn(true)
       
        return;
      } */
      
      };
    
    
      const onSignInPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate('SignIn');
       /* state.logout(); */
    
      };
    
      const onTermsOfUsePressed = () => {
        console.warn('onTermsOfUsePressed');
      };
    
      const onPrivacyPressed = () => {
        console.warn('onPrivacyPressed');
      };
      const [error, setError] = useState({
        username: false,
        email: false,
        password: false,
        passwordRepeat: false
      });
    
      const checkName = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          username: text.length < 5 || text.length > 20
        });
    
        setUser({
          ...user,
          username: text
        });
      };
    
      const checkPrice = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          email: text.length < 5 || text.length > 15
        });
    
        setUser({
          ...user,
          email: text
        });
      };
    
      const checkAuthor = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          password: text.length < 5 || text.length > 15
        });
    
        setUser({
          ...user,
          password: text
        });
      };
    
      const checkContent = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          passwordRepeat: text.length < 2 || text.length > 1000
        });
    
        setUser({
          ...user,
          passwordRepeat: text
        });
      };
      return (
    
        <View showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={styles.root}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Шинэ хэрэглэгчээр бүртгүүлэх</Text>
            {/* <SignInScreen  username = {username} password = {password}/> */}
            <CustomInput
              
              placeholder="Нэвтрэх нэр"
              value={user.username}
              setValue={checkName}
              errorText="Барааны нэрийн урт 4-20 тэмдэгтээс тогтоно."
              errorShow={error.username}
            />
            <CustomInput 
            
            placeholder="Email"
            value={user.email} 
            
            setValue={checkPrice}
            errorText="Бар кодын урт 5 - 15 тооноос тогтоно."
            errorShow={error.email}
            />
            <CustomInput
              placeholder="Нууц үг"
              value={user.password}
              
              setValue={checkAuthor}
              secureTextEntry
              errorText="Номын үнэ 1000 төгрөгөөс дээш байна."
              errorShow={error.password}
            />
            
            <CustomInput
              placeholder="Нууц үг дахин оруулах"
              value={user.passwordRepeat}
              
              setValue={checkContent}
              secureTextEntry
              errorText="Барааны хэмжих нэгж 2 ба түүнээс дээш тэмдэгтээс тогтоно."
              errorShow={error.passwordRepeat}
            />
    
            <CustomButton text="Бүртгүүлэх" onPress={onRegisterPressed} />
    
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Бүртгүүлсээнээр та манай{' '}
              <Text style={styles.link} onPress={onTermsOfUsePressed}>
                Ашиглалтын нөхцөл
              </Text>{' '}
              болон{' '}
              <Text style={styles.link} onPress={onPrivacyPressed}>
                Нууцлалын бодлого{' '}
              </Text>
              -ыг хүлээн зөвшөөрч байна.
            </Text>
    
            <CustomButton
              text="Бүртгэлтэй бол нэвтэрнэ үү"
              onPress={onSignInPress}
              type="SECONDARY"
            />
          </View>
          <Modal4 visible4={visible4} cancel4={() => setVisible4(false)} />
            <Modal5 visible5={visible5} cancel5={() => setVisible5(false)} /> 
            <Modal6 visible6={visible6} cancel6={() => setVisible6(false)} /> 
        </View>
        
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      root: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#051C60',
        margin: 10,
        
      },
      text: {
        color: 'gray',
        marginVertical: 10,
      },
      link: {
        color: '#FDB075',
      },
    });
    
    export default SignUpScreen;
```

signinscreen.js

```js
    import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
    import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
    import { View, Text, Image,StyleSheet,useWindowDimensions,ScrollView,ImageBackground, Alert,Keyboard,TouchableWithoutFeedback,TextInput, } from 'react-native';
    import LOgi from '../../../assets/images/zur.png';
    import CustomInput from '../../components/CustomInput';
    import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
    import ClickImageButton from '../../components/ClickImageButton';
    import image from '../../../assets/images/back.png';
    import Modal1 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal1';    
    import Modal2 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal2' ;
    import Modal3 from '../../components/Ipaddress/Modal3';
    import UserContext from '../../contexts/UserContext';
    import IconModal from '../../components/Ipaddress/IconModal';
    function SignInScreen(props) {
        const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
        const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
        const [visible1, setVisible1] = useState(false);
        const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false);
        
        //login
        const state = useContext(UserContext);
        const {height} = useWindowDimensions();
        const {navigation,route} = props;
        const user = useSelector(state => state.loginReducer.user);
        console.log("USER======",user);
        const product = useSelector(state => state.productsReducer.product)
        console.log("PRODUCTS=======",product)
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        useEffect(() =>{
    
        },[dispatch]);
        useEffect(() =>{
    
        }, [user])
        useEffect(() => {
            const username = route?.params?.username;
            setUsername(username);
            const password = route?.params?.password;
            setPassword(password);
            return () => {
                
            };
          }, []);
        
        const Userhandle = async() =>{
        const existingUser = user.filter(el => el.username === username)[0];
        console.log()
       if(existingUser){
         existingUser.password === password
           ?state.setIsLoggedIn(true)
           :setVisible1(true)
       } else {
         setVisible(true) 
      }
      console.log("useeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrr",username)
     
      
    }        
        const onSignInPressed = () =>{
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        }
        const onSignUpPress = () => {
            console.log('press signup')
            navigation.navigate('SignUp');
            /* state.SignUp(state.setIsLoggedIn(false)); */
            
          };
        const lastNameRef = useRef();
        return (
          
            <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
            <View>            
            
             <View>  
               
              {/* <ClickImageButton/> */}
              <IconModal/>
              <View style={styles.root}>    
                <Image source={LOgi} 
                style= {[styles.logo, {height: height * 0.3}]} 
                resizeMode='contain'/>
                
                <Text style={styles.tect1}>
                    Нэвтрэх нэр
                </Text>
                <CustomInput style={{color: '#ffff'}} 
                placeholder="Нэвтрэх нэр"
                returnKeyType="next"
                autoFocus={true}
                onSubmitEditing={()=> lastNameRef.current.focus()}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                value={username} 
                setValue={setUsername}/>
                <Text style={styles.tect2}>Нууц үг</Text>
                <CustomInput style={{color: '#ffff'}}
                placeholder="Нууц үг" 
                inputref={lastNameRef}
                value={password} 
                setValue={setPassword}
                secureTextEntry/>
    
                <CustomButton text="Нэвтрэх" onPress={Userhandle}/>
                <CustomButton
              text="Бүртгүүлэх"
              onPress={onSignUpPress}
              type="TERTIARY"
            />
                </View>
                
            </View>
            <Modal2 visible1={visible1} cancel1={() => setVisible1(false)} />
            <Modal1 visible={visible} cancel={() => setVisible(false)} />
            <Modal3 visible2={visible2} cancel2={() => setVisible2(false)} /> 
            </View>
    
    </ImageBackground>
    
        );
    
    };
    
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        root:{
            alignItems: "center",
            
        },
        tect1:{
            width: '80%',
            paddingTop:30,
            paddingHorizontal:0,
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 13,
            
        },
        tect2:{
            width: '80%',
            marginTop:20,
            paddingHorizontal:0,
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 13,
            
        },
        logo:{
          
          
          width:180,
          height: 200,
    
        },
        border:{
            borderBottomWidth:1
        },
        img:{
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            width: '100%',
            width: 35,
            marginTop:-30,
            marginRight:20,
            height: 35,
           },
        backgroundImage: {
            flex: 1,
          
            justifyContent: "center"
        }
       
      });
    
    export default SignInScreen;
```

ProductAdd.js

```js
    import React, { useState ,useRef} from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      SafeAreaView,
      StatusBar,
      ScrollView,
      Alert,TouchableWithoutFeedback,
      Keyboard
    } from "react-native";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { mainColor, lightColor, textColor } from "../../../Constants";
    import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
    import FormText from '../../components/PormText/FormText';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton";
    
    import { addProduct } from "../../store/products-actions";
    
    
    const BookAdd = (props) => {
      const [product, setProduct] = useState({
        user_Id:"name1",
        name: "Салями Хиам",
        barcode: "867020022",
        price: "20000",
        units:
          "кг"
      });
      /* const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState() */
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const AddBook = async() =>{
            dispatch(addProduct(product));
        props.navigation.goBack();
    }
      const [error, setError] = useState({
        name: false,
        barcode: false,
        price: false,
        units: false,
        user_Id: false
      });
      const checkName = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          name: text.length < 5 || text.length > 20
        });
        setProduct({
          ...product,
          name: text
        });
      };
      const checkBarcode = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          barcode: text.length < 8 /* || text.length> 8 */
        });
    
        setProduct({
          ...product,
          barcode: text
        });
      };
      const checkPrice = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          price: text < 1000
        });
    
        setProduct({
          ...product,
          price: text
        });
      };
      const checkUnits = text => {
        setError({
          ...error,
          units: text.length > 2 
        });
    
        setProduct({
          ...product,
          units: text
        });
      };
      const checkUserId = text =>{
        setError({
          ...error,
          user_Id: text.length >2 || text.length
        });
        setProduct({
          ...product,
          user_Id: text
        })
      }
      return (
        
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: mainColor }}>
          <Icon size={30} color="#fff" name = "arrow-back-circle-outline" style={{  margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        paddingTop: 0, width:37 }}  onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}/>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor={mainColor} barStyle="dark-content" />     
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              paddingVertical: 0,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              backgroundColor: mainColor
            }}
          > 
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 28,  color: lightColor, marginTop: -5 }}>
              Шинээр бараа нэмэх
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: lightColor, marginTop: 5 }}>
              Та барааны мэдээллээ оруулна уу
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Animatable.View
            animation="fadeInUpBig"
            duration={800}
            style={{
              flex: 5,
              marginTop: -10,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              paddingVertical: 30,
              paddingVertical: 10,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
              borderTopRightRadius: 30
            }}
          >
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
              <FormText
                label="Барааны нэрийг оруулна уу"
                placeholder="Барааны нэр"
                icon="cart-plus"
                value={product.name}
                onChangeText={checkName}
                errorText="Барааны нэрийн урт 4-20 тэмдэгтээс тогтоно."
                errorShow={error.name}
              />
    
              <FormText
                label="Барааны бар кодыг оруулна уу"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                placeholder="Бар код"
                icon="barcode"
                value={product.barcode}
                onChangeText={checkBarcode}
                errorText="Бар кодын урт 8 - 15 тооноос тогтоно."
                errorShow={error.barcode}
              />
    
              <FormText
                label="Барааны үнийг оруулна уу"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                placeholder="Барааэны үнэ"
                icon="currency-usd"
                value={product.price}
                onChangeText={checkPrice}
                errorText="Номын үнэ 1000 төгрөгөөс дээш байна."
                errorShow={error.price}
              />
    
              <FormText
                label="Барааны хэмжих нэгжийг оруулна уу"
                placeholder="тн,кг,гр,тоо ширхэг гэх мэт"
                
                icon="tape-measure"
               
                value={product.units}
                onChangeText={checkUnits}
                errorText="Барааны хэмжих нэгж 2 ба түүнээс дээш тэмдэгтээс тогтоно."
                errorShow={error.units}
              />
              <FormText
                label="Бараа нэмэгчийн нэр"
                placeholder="Нэр"
                icon="cart-plus"
                value={product.user_Id}
                onChangeText={checkUserId}
                errorText="Буруу нэр байна."
                errorShow={error.name}
              /> 
            </ScrollView>
            <CustomButton text="Бүртгүүлэх" type="DIRTARY" onPress={AddBook}/>
          </Animatable.View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        
      );
    };
    
    export default BookAdd;
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

login-reducer.js

```js
    import { ADD_USER, LOAD_USER } from "./login-actions";
    const initialState = {
      user: [],
      username: null,
    };
    
    export default (state = initialState, action)=> {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_USER: {
          console.log("stateeeeee-----------",action.data)
          return {
            user: state.user.concat(action.data?.user),
            username: action.data?.user?.username
          };
        }
        case LOAD_USER: {
          console.log("reducer..",action.data);
          return {
            user: action.data,
            username: action.data.user
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

product-reducer.js

```js
    import { ADD_PRODUCT, LOAD_PRODUCTS } from "./products-actions";
    
    const initialState = {
      product: []
    };
    export default (state = initialState, action)=> {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PRODUCT: {
          console.log("stateeeeee-----------",action.data)
    
          return {
            product: state.product.concat(action.data?.product)
            
          };
        }
        case LOAD_PRODUCTS: {
          console.log("reducer..",action.data);
          return {
            product: action.data
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

App.js

```js
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
    import { UserStore } from './src/contexts/UserContext';
    import Navigation from './src/navigations';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
    import { store,persistor } from './src/redux/store';
    
    const App = ({}) => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
         <Provider store={store}>
           <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
         <UserStore>
          <Navigation/>
          </UserStore>
          </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      root:{
        flex: 1,
       
      },
      
    
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: please format your question

Comment: formatted please check

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: This is already marked as answer In the below link. This worked for me in one of my projects with NextJs. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15687#discussioncomment-45319